# Creating a new point shapefile when vector grid features have a common attribute?

Tags: pyqgis, vector, point, convert

I have a very large shapefile that is composed of many cells. If there are 4 cells together that have the same attribute value, I must locate a point geometry, like below:

[image]

Each side of the cell is 625 meters long. Any ideas are welcomed (QGIS, ArcGIS, or code in PyQGIS...).

Answer (score 3):

You could convert to raster with a cell size of 1250(2 times the vector grid cell size). Then you would convert back to vector, select the cells that have the desired attribute and take their centroids. You would then conduct a spatial join between the centroids and the original layer, taking the attributes of all original cells that touch the centroids in order to weed out any error centroids that were created due to a majority of desirable attributes as apposed to a complete four cells block as pictured below.

[image: Example of area that may return a false centroid]

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution using QGIS (PyQGIS). Starting from this vector grid, which has been categorized using the same color for common attributes values from the `"MY_FIELD"` field):

[image]

you may run the following code from the **Python Console**:

```
from qgis.core import *
layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/path_to_file/filename.shp', 'test', 'ogr') # Edit the filepath
comparing_attr = 'MY_FIELD' # Edit the field name

# Create the output layer
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs='+ crs, 'common' , 'memory')
prov = outLayer.dataProvider()
fields = layer.pendingFields()
for field in fields:
    if field.name() == comparing_attr:
        field_type = field.typeName()
        field_length = field.length()
        new_field = [field]
prov.addAttributes(new_field)
outLayer.updateFields()

attrs_dict = {}
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    tmp_coords = feat.geometry().asPolygon()
    points = []
    for i in tmp_coords:
        points.extend(i)
    coords=list(set(points))

    if feat[comparing_attr] not in attrs_dict.keys():
        attrs_dict[feat[comparing_attr]] = coords
    else:
        attrs_dict[feat[comparing_attr]].extend(coords)

for key, vals in attrs_dict.iteritems():
    common=[x for x in vals if vals.count(x) >= 4]
    already_processed = []
    for item in common:
        if item not in already_processed:
            geom=QgsGeometry.fromPoint(item)
            outGeom = QgsFeature()
            outGeom.setGeometry(geom)
            outGeom.setAttributes([key])
            prov.addFeatures([outGeom])
            already_processed.append(item)

# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
```

and it will return a point memory layer which stores the value of the common attribute:

[image]

The only thing that you need to do is properly adapting the code to your specific case, i.e. you need to specify the filepath of the layer and the name of the attribute of interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try with Pyqgis code. I have check the first raster option and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @NataliaBernal well, remember to properly edit the second and the third line of the code.

Comment: @NataliaBernal any news?